# How to count total number of record for each 7 days in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, counting

i trying to get data from database with counting the total number start from today  and auto reduce 1 days and count for 7 time. It will display like

```
Monday    = 5
Tuesday   = 2
Wednesday = 6
Thursday  = 4
Friday    = 7
Saturday  = 1
Sunday    = 5
```

The problems is when my using the query below

```
SELECT count(*), ad_date 
  FROM advertise
 WHERE ad_date >=ad_date(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
```

It showing error:

> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'

So what is the problems for this or any alternative query for my problems?

The format of my date table is using timestamp.

```
2016-03-23 14:27:28 
2016-03-25 18:27:28 
2016-03-26 18:27:28`
```

Comment: You may want to re-read the [datediff() documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) for MySQL instead of the documentation for SQL Server. They have different parameters.

Comment: The solution you've described in comments below appears to use a loop. Performance must be deeply unsatisfactory. If so, consider revising your question to include representative data and a desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

datediff has only two parameters

> DATEDIFF(date1,date2)

1. startdate where you want to starts from
2. EndDate

Replace:

> datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)

With:

> DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY),GetDate())

Updated Answer (Try This):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM table_name
WHERE created_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
Group by created_date
```

Comment: if change to SELECT count(*), ad_date FROM advertise
WHERE ad_date >=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)) the output will display the total number in table and oldest date in table.

Comment: Currently i need to count the total number of each days, is there possible using for loop in the query?

Comment: Dear I answered only about the Error you showed. If you need the result do not go for the for loop use Sub Queries. Let me help you with that.

Comment: I used a loop and execute for 7 time, each time interval 1 days and increase the value of days, the problems solved.Thank for your help.

Comment: If we now have Saturday 12:00 then `created_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)` will also match last Saturday 14:00. I don't know if OP want that. If not, you could rewrite the condition to `date(ad_date) > CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY` or something like  `ad_date >= timestamp(date(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY), '00:00:00')` so an index can be used.